# Создание ненумерованного списка из массива

Tags: javascript, html

Вообще суть моей задачи состоит в создании онлайн теста на JS. При этом мне необходимо использовать такой шаблон массива. И у меня все никак не выходит создать список из этого бреда
И да, не обращайте внимание на код после //
Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы на страницу выводился список с вопросами. Ну и если не сложно, как сделать тоже самое с ответами (ну логично, чтобы их можно было выбирать)

````
        const question1 =  [
            {
                question1: 'Kto ubil Marka?',
                answers: [
                    { text: 'Oksi', correct: true },
                    { text2: 'Mark', correct: false }
                ]
            }
        ]
        const question2 =  [
            {
                question2: 'Da ili net?',
                answers: [
                    { text: 'net', correct: true },
                    { text2: 'da', correct: false }
                ]
            }
        ]
       //document.getElementById("que").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(question1[1]);
        html = '<ul>';
        question1.forEach(function (item, i, arr){
            html += '<li>' +item+'</li>';
        });
        html += '/<ul>'
    </script>```
````

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

Ну структура вопросов у вас явно неправильная. Лучше всё в один массив сделать, где каждый элемент это вопрос с данными. И использовать его для генерации вопросов.

```js
const questions = [{
    question: 'Кто убил Марка?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Окси', id: 1 },
      { text: 'Марк', id: 2 }
    ],
    correct: 1
  },
  {
    question: 'Да или нет?',
    answers: [
      { text: 'Нет', id: 3 },
      { text: 'Да', id: 4 }
    ],
    correct: 3
  }
];

const makeQuestion = (data) => {
  const makeAnswerVariant = (data, question) => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'radio';
    input.id = data.id;
    input.name = question;
    const label = document.createElement('label');
    label.setAttribute('for', data.id);
    label.textContent = data.text;
    li.append(input, label);
    return li;
  };

  const question = document.createElement('h3');
  question.textContent = data.question;

  const variants = data.answers.map((item) => {
    return makeAnswerVariant(item, data.question);
  });

  const list = document.createElement('ul');
  list.append(...variants);

  return [question, list];
};

const makeQuiz = (questions) => {
  const items = questions.flatMap(makeQuestion);
  const wrapper = document.querySelector('.questions');
  wrapper.append(...items);
};

makeQuiz(questions);
```

```html
<div class="questions"></div>
```